# Can I wear a helmet without penalty if I don't have armor proficiency?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

All the helms in the books seem to be illustrated like armor. When a character without armor proficiency wears a magic helm, does he suffer the same penalties as if he wore other armor?  In the DMG, the illustration makes helms appear armored.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Helms are not Armor

Helms are considered *wondrous items* and thus neither benefit your armor class nor require proficiency with any kind of armor.

Comment: You may want to add that they also don't contribute to AC.

Comment: You also might want to revise to say "helm", since none of the items use the word helmet. It probably doesn't make a tremendous amount of difference, but we might as well make sure to use the given terms.

Comment: I was not aware of the difference between helms and helmets. TIL. Fixed.

Comment: It would be good to refer to the armor table and note the absence of helms or helmets as separate items on that table. p 145 phb

Comment: @KorvinStarmast except full plate does include a helmet. It's not a separate item, like you say, but it would interfere with using both a helm and full plate and it is an example of helmet-that-is-armor.

Comment: Fun note: A helm is an archaic term for helmet. They literally mean the same thing.

Comment: @nitsua60 Indeed, that exception either makes a difference or it doesn't depending on how the DM wants to treat the "wonderous item" in that case.  But that's a good point.  The AC of Full Plate doesn't indicate how much of it is from helm ... ruling required.

Comment: Important note: A DM could easily just say that any headgear has the magical properties described under that entry in the DMG. Your "Helm of Comprehend Languages" could be a Wizard Hat or a Fur Headband. If for no other reason than this being D&D 5e.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I don't know if this holds up in modern editions, but in 3.5, there was a specific line in the DMG stating that replacing the helmet from a suit of armor with magical headgear did not change the AC bonus in any way.